# T-SQL INSERT - Increment value when other columns are duplicated

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, conditional-statements, increment

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Budget (
Year Int,
Region varchar(50),
Amount float,
DraftNo int);

GO

INSERT INTO Budget 
VALUES
(2018, 'Region1', 500000, 1),
(2018, 'Region2', 400000, 1),
(2018, 'Region3', 300000, 1);
```

End users will submit data for Year, Region, and Amount through an Excel form, which will use VBA to write INSERT statements against the table.  DraftNo will be 1 by default, but if there is already a match in the table on the first two columns (Year and Region), I want to increment DraftNo by one each time.

For example, if the application tries to write:

```
INSERT INTO Budget VALUES (2018, 'Region1', 600000, 1)
```

It should be converted to:

```
INSERT INTO Budget VALUES (2018, 'Region1', 600000, 2)
```

Of course, the solution will also need to recognize the max draft number for the Year/Region combination and increment one more from there, rather than always using 2.

Comment: You are looking for `merge`.

Comment: I tried with MERGE but I was not able to figure out how to run an alternative insert rather than just updating the existing record when the source and targets were matched.  If it's possible, an example would be really helpful.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. This is what `merge` for. But you don't have to use merge, alternatively you can use update/insert (in stored procedure, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If you need to add new record with incremental DraftNo:

```
declare @y int = 2018, @r varchar(50) = 'Region6', @a float = 3

INSERT INTO Budget VALUES (@y, @r, @a, isnull((select max(DraftNo) from Budget where [Year] = @y and Region = @r), 0) + 1)
```

### If you need update existing records and add DraftNo:

**Using `MERGE`:**

```
merge Budget as trg
using (select 2018, 'Region1', 600000) as src (y, r, a)
on trg.[Year] = src.y and trg.[Region] = src.r and trg.Amount = src.a
when matched then
    update set DraftNo = DraftNo + 1
when not matched then
    insert ([Year], Region, Amount, DraftNo)
    values (y, r, a, 1);
```

**Using `Update` + `Insert`:**

```
declare @y int = 2018, @r varchar(50) = 'Region6', @a float = 3

update Budget 
set DraftNo = DraftNo + 1
where [Year] = @y and [Region] = @r and Amount = @a

if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    insert Budget (Year, Region, Amount, DraftNo)
    values (@y, @r, @a, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples, Mike.  They are not quite working the way I need them to, though.  I don't want to update the draft number in any existing records, I want to add a new record when Year and Region are matched.  So, if I run an INSERT for 2018, Region1 (with any amount - I don't need to check for a match on Amount) , I should now have 4 records in the table.  the new record would be (2018, Region1, 600000, 2)

Comment: Oh, if you never need to update record, you just need simple INSERT, no need for MERGE or UPDATE statements.

Comment: I updated my answer, please see if this is what you need.

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thank you so much!